# Wrong totals in Report Builder - Avg and Sum

Tags: reporting-services

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeYZ6.jpg)I am new to Report Builder and is trying to add totals per year and grand total for a report.
The totals are not showing the result I expected, so either my normal rows are made wrong (which I dont think so, but possible), or the Total calculations are made wrong.
Can you assist?

**Row expressions for P&L Actual**
All rows, including my normal rows and Total Year and Total is: =Avg(Fields!Diff_Spread_RT_CS.Value)*sum(Fields!ActVol_Total.Value)

**Row expressions for [A-B]**
All the same: =Avg(Fields!Diff_Spread_RT_CS.Value)
Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks for help

Comment: Please provide some data, the output of your report and expected output

Comment: I added a picture, thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Still it is not very clear why your calculations are failing. We need detail data to reproduce the "wrong" calculations for the totals and help you fix your expressions.